# Replace atom in array of strings

Tags: j

Suppose I have an array of strings `"31,793.1" "29,798.6" "30,455.7" "29,700.9"`

How do I replace `,` with nothing to give me `"31793.1" "29798.6" "30455.7" "29,700.9"`

Another example is to replace `-` in  `"-5" "-3" "-4"` with `_` to give  `"_5" "_3" "_4"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"31,793.1" "29,798.6" "30,455.7" "29,700.9"` would not be an "array of strings" in J. I will suppose that you have a line like this and you want to end up with an array of numbers:

```
data =: '"31,793.1" "29,798.6" "30,455.7" "29,700.9" "-5"'

NB. Convert commas to "null" and '-'s to '_'s
NB. rplc works in pairs 'old';'new'
data rplc ',';'';'-';'_'
"31793.1" "29798.6" "30455.7" "29700.9" "_5"

NB. remove '"'s
data rplc '"';''
31793.1 29798.6 30455.7 29700.9 _5
```

Normally now you would have to split on whitespace (there are many ways to do this) but converting to numbers using `".` takes care of this here:

```
 NB. ". data
 31793.1 29798.6 30455.7 29700.9 _5

 +/ data
 121743
```